# kubernetes node version not shown properly in the controller node, but each worker node shows the correct upgraded version

Tags: kubernetes

I just did the upgrade lab. Somehow it was messed up because the lab because the Cloud Guru didnt mention that I had to do gradual upgrade from 1.24 to 1.25, then 1.26 , then 1.27.2. I figured it out myself and did it. All the nodes shows the correct version in CLI. But when I check it in the control node, it shows me that the worker nodes are on 1.26.0.

I did the drain, update/upgrade kubeadm, to upgrade plan/apply kubeadm, then update upgrade the kubelet and kubect. reloaded daemon and kubelet. In the nodes, I did the "sudo kubeadm upgrade node" instead. What am I missing?

Output from the control node, showing worker1 and worker2 on 1.26.0

```
root@k8s-control:/# kubectl get nodes

NAME STATUS ROLES AGE VERSION

k8s-control Ready control-plane 5d14h v1.27.2

k8s-worker1 NotReady,SchedulingDisabled 5d13h v1.26.0

k8s-worker2 NotReady,SchedulingDisabled 5d13h v1.26.0
```

And this is the output from one of the worker node, it shows 1.27.2

```
root@k8s-worker2:/# kubeadm version

kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"27", GitVersion:"v1.27.2", GitCommit:"7f6f68fdabc4df88cfea2dcf9a19b2b830f1e647", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-05-17T14:18:49Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

```
root@k8s-worker2:/# kubectl version

WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced with the output from kubectl version --short. Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"27", GitVersion:"v1.27.2", GitCommit:"7f6f68fdabc4df88cfea2dcf9a19b2b830f1e647", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-05-17T14:20:07Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Kustomize Version: v5.0.1

The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

```
root@k8s-worker2:/# kubelet --version

Kubernetes v1.27.2
```

So I just started studying for CKA. Its been a while since I touch the devops type of study. Last time I got Redhat 7 cert, then Openstack study for a while and work on the lab. But since the beginning of the Covid, I didn't touch any Linux related study. I am little rusty. Anyways, my work is moving towards devops and even my title is devops engineer, but not doing much devops related stuff. I mostly work on load balancers and firewalls. I started to study for CKA exam which our company have a product related to kubernetes. I got stack in the upgrade lab. I did it like 3 times, but cant get the controller node to show the correct version even though the workers are on the correct version.

I upgraded the controller and each node from 1.24.0 to 1.27.2 version. But Kubeadm get nodes show that the workers are at 1.26.0 while their worker shows that they are in correct version when you login to them and check it in their CLI.

Below are the steps I did.

Drain the control node and the worker node before i start working on them. And on the nodes, I did "sudo kubeadm upgrade node" instead of upgrade plan and apply.

```
kubectl drain k8s-control --ignore-daemonsets --force
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install -y --allow-change-held-packages kubeadm=1.27.2-00

sudo kubeadm upgrade plan v1.27.2
sudo kubeadm upgrade apply
Upgrade kubelet sudo apt-get update && \ sudo apt-get install -y --allow-change-held-packages kubelet=1.27.2-00 kubectl=1.27.2-00

sudo systemctl daemon-reload 
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
kubectl uncordon k8s-control
```